# Can only connect to httpd on 443 with IP address, hostname SSL handshake fails

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, openssl

I've come across a very strange issue.  On our server, we are running Solaris 10 with httpd 2.2.19 and openssl 1.0.0d.  We have only a single virtual host:

`<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName hostname.example.com:443`

With hostname being the correct hostname of course.  When we go to navigate to the site using the hostname, the connection fails and I see in the error_log that teh SSL handshake starts, shows the BIO dump, then says:

> [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1884): OpenSSL:> Write: SSLv3 read client hello C
>
> [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Exit: error in error
>
> [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1903): OpenSSL: Exit: error in error
>
> [info] [client 1x.x.x.x] SSL library error 1 in handshake (server hostname.example.com:443)
>
> [info] SSL Library Error: 336204149 error:140A1175:SSL routines:SSL_BYTES_TO_CIPHER_LIST:inappropriate fallback
>
> [info] [client x.x.x.x] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server hostname.example.com:443)
>
> [notice] child pid 28997 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /usr/local/apache2/logs

Does anybody have any idea what the issue might be? I can't for the life of me think why the hostname would be handled differently from the IP.  We have SSL3 protocol disabled in the config, and a long list of ciphers enabled that work on other servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the port number in the ServerName.

Also are you using NameBased virtual hosting? If so don't use *default* but use * instead.

So instead of this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName hostname.example.com:443
</VirtualHost>
```

have this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName hostname.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Per the docs http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#default:

> A default vhost never serves a request that was sent to an
>   address/port that is used for name-based vhosts. If the request
>   contained an unknown or no Host: header it is always served from the
>   primary name-based vhost (the vhost for that address/port appearing
>   first in the configuration file).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  We are not using NameBased virtual hosting.  Also, although I see what you mean about the port, we have another server with pretty much the same exact config, and it seems to work properly

Answer (score 0):

So I found the way to fix it, but I'm not 100% sure why this resolved it. I changed the ServerName from hostname.subdomain.domain:443, to hostname.domain:443.  The proper name of the server is hostname.subdomain.domain, but I noticed in the hosts file that the IP for this server has:

```
*IP* hostname hostname.domain
```

Could this be why?  Why would the SSL get all screwy from this?